# can we hide/invisible UIPicker/DatePicker on iPhone view?

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I have tried with setting properties of UIPicker as SetHidden:False and SetVisible:NO , but they are still visible.

Comment: Is the UIPicker part of a .xib (Interface Builder) file or is it instantiated via a custom UIView subclass?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to say "`setHidden:True`", and not False, yeah?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, you should use "setHidden", not "setVisible" and you should use "YES", not "False" or "NO", so try "setHidden:YES", it should work if the UIPicker is correctly connected in Interface Builder.

And please copy the code directly from XCode instead of retyping it. It is "setHidden" with a small "s" and not with a capital "S".

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an IBOutlet and set the link up for the referencing outlet?

Answer (score 0):

`[picker setHidden:YES];`

Or `picker.hidden = YES;`

Don't forget that if you had dragged & dropped a UIDatePicker object onto your view using Interface Builder, you must link your object to the defined variable. You can do that by holding the CTRL button while dragging from your UIDatePicker object on your view to the File's Owner. I actually forget to do that more often than not. I end up programmatically creating my objects and adding them as subviews as a result.